# Using Http client

Tags: java, web-services, http, httpclient

I am new to web services,but some how managed to create a web service after reading some docs.
I am able to get wsdl file also with fallowing loaction : 
**//?wsdl.**
Generated WSDL also contains my methods(API's) and i am able to test the same with SOAP UI.
But now i need to get the response in browser,so i decided to use HTTP client as fallows:-

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

```
    HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(
    "http://<localhost>/<serviceName>/getCustomerAttributesById?CustomerId=60000");
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);


    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader
      (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    String line = "";
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println("o/p Line:"+line);
    }
```

But o/p line is always empty.what might be the reason.Please help me.

Comment: A web service with a WSDL implies a SOAP service but you are not making a SOAP client call, am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set timeout on http connection. Here is sample code.

```
HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(
"http://<localhost>/<serviceName>/getCustomerAttributesById?CustomerId=60000");

HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
int timeout = 50000;
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeout);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeout);

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader
  (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println("o/p Line:"+line);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick respnse.My problem here is that i am unable to invoke getCustomerAttributesById method itself.I have include some chcekpoints inside this method to ensure whether it in invoked or not.but it is not invoking at all.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like it should work if the url is correct and the service actually returns something. You might want to check the response status and see if it actually returns 200 (OK). Alternatively paste the URL in a browser and see what comes back.

If all else fails, you might want to turn on debug logging for httpclient. http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging.html

BTW. you might want to consider using a ResponseHandler, your code could fail to release the connection properly.